# Ansible creating two file

Tags: ansible

I am using Ansbile 2.9 with python 3.6.9 . I created a script to capture "show-tech" from cisco nxos.

So in my script i saved showtech file on bootflash than i copy it to ansible controller into specific folder using net_get module

All seem to work fine but issue i see is ansible is creating one additional outfile with random name like "0d4cfa0ae57-439d-48ef-aac0-944a882ddcb"

This file has identical data which i copied from device and stored in specific location.

So my question is why Ansible is creating this additional file and how to make it stop?

```
  - name: "creating local folder cisco-nxos-showtech"
        file:
          path: cisco-nxos-showtech
          state: directory
          mode: '777'


      - name: Copying file from nxos device to local cisco-nxos-showtech folder
        net_get:
          src: "showtech-{{ ansible_net_hostname }}
          dest: "cisco-nxos-showtech"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ansible uses temporary files during operations. Check your ansible.cfg file and specify local_tmp folder as desired. Read more here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg

Comment: In my case it does not look to be tmp file and it is created in same folder from where i run ansible-playbook.

Comment: Invoke your playbook with -vvvv flag and read log messages carefully. There are going to be at least some hints if not a definitive answer. Post your log if it's not clear.